# Need help finding which category has no items - New to SQL/Access

Tags: sql

I'm totally new to SQL/Access and I would appreciate your help on this task:

I have 2 tables, `Articles` and `Categories`. Items in `Articles` have an attribute for `ID_Category` ... Items in `Categories` have an attribute for `Category`.

**I need to find which `Category` has no `Articles`.**

[Relationships.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaKXw.png)

I'm attaching a screenshot of my relationship between the 2 tables if this is of any help, again, I'd really appreciate your help as I'm clueless at this point :( This is the last task I have to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists`:

```
select c.*
from categories as c
where not exists (select 1
                  from articles as a
                  where a.category_id = c.category
                 );
```